# Web log files analyzer

Tags: logging, web

I already use Google Analytics on my page, but I'd like to get additional info from log files. I've looked at various packages during last days, but nothing impressed me so far.

Some requirements:

- must work on log file level (I use apache combined logs, but can configure apache to produce other types of logs)
- can generate static reports (windows/linux) or use GUI (windows only)
- should be easy to add custom user agents, and rerun analysis
- if it can recognize installation of eclipse plugins from log, that would be big plus
- understands google serp position referer
- should not require two days to setup (awstats, I am looking at you)
- should be still under active developement (i.e. analog isn't good answer)
- preferrably free, or at not very expensive :-)

Any good analyzers programs out there?

Comment: I was going to suggest AWStats, which I found easy to set up, but you're not keen on it.

Comment: Well, AWStats is top on my list, but I hope to find something better with easier configuration. I used to use awstats some 6-7 years ago, and it was pretty good ... but it's INSTALL file hasn't really improved since then :-(

Comment: Analog IS under active development

Answer (score 2):

Free, and comes packaged in many Linux distros, is [The Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/).

> *The Webalizer* is a fast, free web server log file analysis program. It produces highly detailed, easily configurable usage reports in HTML format, for viewing with a standard web browser.
>
> Handles standard Common  logfile format (CLF) server logs, several variations of the NCSA Combined  logfile format, wu-ftpd/proftpd  xferlog (FTP) format logs,  Squid proxy server native format, and W3C Extended log formats. In addition, gzip (.gz) and bzip2 (.bz2) compressed logs may be used directly without the need for uncompressing.

Comment: this question and answers are ancient. However, I can tell you that in 2022, this tool is still working, and [Webmin](https://webmin.com/) provides a no brains module to access basic statistics. Updated link to the [Webalizer](https://webalizer.net) website

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [WebLog Expert](http://www.weblogexpert.com).  It's got a GUI and a scheduler so reports can be updated and waiting for you in the morning.

Comment: Hits all the bullets wanted by OP save for the Google SERPs

Answer (score 1):

I like [Visitors](http://www.hping.org/visitors/), which has a nice output - and can create a graph of how people click around the website, using graphviz.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried it out yet: web log analzyer is **[Deep Log Analyzer](http://www.deep-software.com/)**. There is a free and a commercial version. Here is the [feature list page](http://www.deep-software.com/dla.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Webalizer and Google Analytics, but another one to try is [Clicky](http://getclicky.com/111485). It's easy to install, you just sign up for a free account and paste some javascript that they provide onto your page. Dead simple, and provides a lot of information. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it seems that Clicky doesn't use log files for analysis. One of my sites is accessed by clients *without* javascript (various eclipse-based products).

Answer (score 0):

I like Flashstats: http://www.maximized.com/products/flashstats2006/

I download my apache logs via ftp to my machine and then run the Windows Executable version of flashstats. It produces tons of useable reports.