# GUI program to locally analyze server / web logs?

Tags: logging, web, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web log files analyzer](https://superuser.com/questions/7790/web-log-files-analyzer)

I have a web server log file locally that I would like to extract unique visitors and downloads from, possibly visualised on a time-line.
However, all the analysis software I can find does so via a web UI:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_log_analysis_software
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software

Is there a program that has a GUI?

Comment: It's not a duplicate - I'm asking specifically for a GUI.